# How to train Wit.ai for languages other then english?

Tags: wit.ai

How do u input different languages on Wit.ai.
I have tried writing the other languages in english and training.
But I want to train it on the languages own script.

Answer (score 1):

wit already support lots of languages, you can see list of supported languages [here](https://wit.ai/faq). Just start training wit with any of supported languages and remember to set the language in app setting.

Comment: Does it use the English font for other languages? or the respective fonts of the languages ?

Comment: No! you can write in your language! it support utf-8 so you can write text in any language you want!